# javafx change background image via setStyle for selected/hovered ToggleButton

Tags: java, css, javafx, togglebutton

I have a ToggleGroup of ToggleButtons that should have the same style when unselected but each a different style when selected or hovered. I already found how this works with colors:

```
.my-toggle-button{
    -fx-background-color: grey;
}
.my-toggle-button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mycolor;
}
.my-toggle-button:selected{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mycolor;
}
```

In my program, I can now set `-fx-mycolor` dynamically:

```
button.setStyle("-fx-mycolor: "+color);
```

where button is one of many ToggleButtons and color is a dynamically generated String.

This works just as expected: Each button has its own color when hovered over and keeps it when selected. If a different button gets selected, the previously selected button in the ToggleGroup snaps back to grey.

Now what I want is to do this with background images. I tried using

```
.toggle-button-fret-nonzero:selected{
    -fx-background-image: url(-fx-myimage);
}
```

and then set it in Java via `setStyle("-fx-myimage: "+image)` but this doesn't work (CSS tries to load an image named `-fx-myimage`).

How can I achieve the behaviour demonstrated with colors for images?

I already tried to use `setStyle("-fx-background-image: url("+image+");")` directly on certain mouse-events like hovering or clicking but that's not what I want because then the button does not snap back to grey when another button is selected.

I would also like to avoid to define CSS-classes for every possible button since they are many.

**EDIT**: I solved the issue by using `setStyle("-fx-background-image: url("+image+");")` method and manually iterating over every button on every click, resetting the background-image accordingly. This works fine now, it's just that it feels like a hack since it's basically reimplementing the functionality of a ToggleButton...

Comment: The only place where "looked-up" is mentioned in the [CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) is for colors. Probably it's impossible to do it this way...